# Issue converting DD/MM/YYYY hh:ii date to YYYY/MM/DD hh:ii MYSQL

Tags: mysql, datetime

Been searching for ages to try and find an answer for this but got no luck.

I have a column with a Datetime type. I have a field on a webpage which has an input control which puts the date in this format 20-12-2015 23:30 .When I try and store this I just get blank entries or 0000-00-00 00:00:000

The field likes the date in this format 2015-20-12 23:15:00

Can anybody help me please help me work out how to convert this correctly. I have been trying with several Date_Format methods but all give me an error

> "1292 Incorrect datetime value: '10/12/2015 10:50'"

Comment: Maybe interesting? [SQLFidde to play with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0fcd7/1). [Instructions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format)

Answer (score 1):

If you have a fixed format date being returned from the page that is not a compatible date, and you cannot change the format used on the page, then before you attempt to store it on the database you need to convert it to a compatible format.

PHP has a DateTime object that does exactly this

```
<?php
$in = '20-12-2015 23:30';

$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d-m-Y H:i', $in);
$to_db_date = $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');

echo $to_db_date;
```

This produces a MySQL compatible date string like

```
2015-12-20 23:30:00
```